Mosque in jerusalem
In the hadith of isra Miraj
""They continued travelling until they reached the valley that is in the city — that is: the Hallowed House (Jerusalem) — when lo and behold! the Gehenna was shown to them like a carpet unfolded. They (the Companions) said: “O Messenger of Allah, how was it?” He replied: “Like cinders.”
He continued travelling until he reached the city of the Hallowed House and he entered it by its Southern gate. He dismounted the Buraq and tied it at the gate of the mosque, using the ring by which the Prophets tied it before him. One narration states that Jibril came to the Rock and placed his fingers in it, piercing it, then he tied the Buraq using the spot he had hollowed out.
The Prophet entered the mosque from a gate through which the sun and the moon could be seen when they set. He prayed two cycles of prayer and did not tarry long before a large throng of people had gathered.""
This is the description of the mosque in jerusalem and given in the hadith. But historically we know that the temple had been destroyed in the first century and wasnt rebuilt till the 7th/8th century.
How do we explain the details mentioned about the mosque by hadith, if the mosque itself was in ruins at the time of the miraaj?

This is a (night = dream?) vision, not a travel report.
"The Gehenna was shown to them like a carpet unfolded". The Gehenna cannot be visited in Jerusalem, neither today nor in that time.
There are mentions of a "Heavenly Jerusalem" in the (Christian) vision of John as well as in Jewish 2nd century midrashim. I would interprete this as the Islamic vision on the Heavenly Jerusalem.

Sorry for the spam but I'd like to invite your for participating at the Mod-Election see in our Meta
